# How to reuse views in prism/mef

Tags: silverlight, prism, mef

Using Silverlight 5, Prism 4.1 and MEF.

I have a view, that is exported by its interface.

Sample:

```
[Export(typeof(IUploadListView)), PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public partial class UploadListView : RadWindow, IUploadListView
{
}
```

I have a model (let say a main menu model), that want to reuse this view 2 times. Each instance of the view must be invoked and shown just once. I change the UploadType on the underlaying viewmodel, so that the behavior will change.

Sample:

```
var view = this.serviceLocator.GetInstance<IUploadListView>();
view.UploadListViewModel.UploadType = UploadType.MyType1;
view.Show();
```

and the other menu option:

```
var view = this.serviceLocator.GetInstance<IUploadListView>();
view.UploadListViewModel.UploadType = UploadType.MyType2;
view.Show();
```

The problem is this:

- When using the NonShared policy I do get unique instances showable. The problem than is that the instance is shown twice (or more) when the user presses the same menu item.
- When using the Shared policy, when the first view is shown, the 2nd menu item will reuse the 1st view, so only 1 view is shown.

What I want is that I must be able check if there is an instance of type IUploadListView shown, and when that happens, I just reuse the instance and call Show(). When there is no instance found, I want MEF to create it for me (with the service locator).

Is there a way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement [INavigationAware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.inavigationaware%28v=pandp.38%29.aspx) interface in your view or its view model and take advantage of the `IsNavigationTarget` method.

When `RequestNavigate` is called for a region, the `IsNavigationTarget` will be invoked to allow the instance of the view to decide whether it should be activated. If it returns true, the view will be activated. Otherwise Prism will create a new instance of the view, place it in the region and activate it.

See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861(v=pandp.40).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) for more details.